# Bug report - unable to comment or ask a question on the Meta using the app

Tags: bug

Whenever I try to comment or ask a question on the Meta page in the app, I am told ‘the app submitted an invalid request Please let us know on meta’. So... I’m letting you know on meta.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[The mobile apps are no longer supported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342028/268944).  Instead, you should be using the regular website, which should work properly on mobile devices.

Comment: Ah okay, thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 3):

While Mark's answer is correct, I wanna add some points:

- When the app said to 'let us know on meta' it means to post a topic on the main meta of SE, [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/). That's how the SE staff is tracking bugs and issues with the site and apps.
- While users are encouraged to use the "responsive" website, you can still the app if you wish to. This problem looks like it's backend related and not an actual bug of the app.

  ["There will not be any more builds"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/343967/388884)  indicates that any bug on the app will not be fixed but backend errors [can be fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/343967/android-app-not-showing-feed), they don't really involve modifications to the app code.

With that said, I think you should think of reporting this issue (search first before asking!) but if the website is more handy for you, use it.

Comment: Ah that makes sense - I searched in the Drones and Model Aircraft meta to see if anyone had mentioned the issue already and they hadn’t, but it makes much more sense that I would need to post in the Stack Exchange meta instead. Thanks.